# How to get the camera local axis in three.js

Tags: camera, three.js, local

I would like to know what is the most simple/elegant way to get the **normalize local axis (x, y, z)** of a perspective camera in three.js.

[image]

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

well i'm not that use to OOP, but if you have the enlightment to check 2 class upstairs, there is **Object3D** **class** that looks to have all the **methods** i need.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D